# Restoring BackInTime snapshot to new computer - copy config and change host name hasn't worked

Tags: backup, restore

My new system has a different name than the previous one, and BackInTime doesn't recognize the snapshot files. I'm a novice user of Ubuntu.

I found the config file in the backup and copied it to Home/ .config/ backintime. I opened Settings in BackInTime, and under the General tab, clicked advanced, unchecked 'Auto Host', and changed the Host and User fields to what they were on the previous system, and refreshed the snapshot list, but it still doesn't recognize the backup.

So what steps do I need to take?

Edit - I'm actually just copying the files back now. Because it is called a snapshot, I thought it was like a disk image and you couldn't do that, but the files can be opened. Kind of laborious but not tragic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy&Paste from my [answer on Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/backintime/+question/271242):

Please use current BackInTime version from our PPA. I added a 'restore config' function in there. If BIT doesn't find a config it will ask if you would like to restore it. Than you just need to choose the snapshot from which you would like to restore and hit enter. Also the `Auto Host/User/ProfileID` setting is gone as this confuses everyone in your situation.

To use our PPA run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bit-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you still can't see your snapshots, make sure the snapshot path is correct. Maybe your external drive is mounted in a different place than on your old machine!?

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm member of the BackInTime Dev-Team</sub>